# Surprising value assignment due to operator precedence?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Original question based on completely wrong logic :O

```
$(function() {
  var x=0,y=1;
  $("#div_id").find("input:text").each(function (i, input)  {
    $(this).val(""+(i % 2 == 0)?x++:y++);
  });
});
```

If I remove the ""+ from the value, I get this wrong result

[image]

instead of what I want, which is this:

[image]

Same if I use prop:

```
    $(this).prop("value",""+(i % 2 == 0)?x++:y++);
```

Same if I prefix the ++

What am I overlooking? Is this an obvious thing?

---

*UPDATE*: I completely missed the boat here.

Here is the code I meant to write and it works without the ""

```
$(function() {
  var x=0,y=1;
  var inputs = $("#div_id").find("input:text");
  var y = Math.ceil(inputs.size()/2);
  inputs.each(function (i, input)  {
    $(this).prop("value",(i % 2 == 0)?++x:++y);
  });
});
```

Comment: The obvious workaround is `$(this).val(i)`: you're just counting from 0, aren't you?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
"" + (i % 2 == 0) ? x++ : y++
```

is interpreted as (see [precedence rules](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence))

```
("" + (i % 2 == 0)) ? x++ : y++
```

and `("" + (i % 2 == 0))` is always truthy, because both `"true"` and `"false"` are non-empty strings. So in your example, you're using `x++` all the time, ignoring the `y++` branch.

Comment: +1. This is because [`+` has a higher precedence than `:?`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence).

Comment: Got the code to do what I wanted with the boolean I wanted - thanks

Answer (score 1):

It seems the [**associativity**](http://www.scriptingmaster.com/javascript/operator-precedence.asp)  of + operator which is from left to right of expression. If you remove `""+` only `(i % 2 == 0)` makes condition part of conditional operator which will be evaluated to true of false. but if you include it will not evaluated to boolean rather string and would be true always.

With string you will always get true

```
alert("" + false ? "true" : "false");
```

**[Live Demo](http://jsbin.com/ahunif/2/edit)**